# npm-shrinkwrap.json appends ?dl=https://registry.npmjs.org/... to all "resolved" properties

Tags: npm, artifactory, npm-shrinkwrap

When I am using the command `npm install` all `resolved` properties of npm-shrinkwrap.json append `?dl=https://registry.npmjs.org/<package-name>`.

Example

```
...,
"@types/hammerjs": {
  "version": "2.0.35",
  "resolved": "https://npm.artifactory.transactdevops.com:443/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/@types/hammerjs/-/hammerjs-2.0.35.tgz?dl=https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/hammerjs/-/hammerjs-2.0.35.tgz",
  "integrity": "<key>",
  "dev": true
},
...
```

The packages are from Artifactory and .npmrc does not seem to have anything to do with it.

I don't know what "dl" means and the reason this needless addition occurs, but I would like to keep a clean file when I'll add (`npm i --save`) or update dependencies and share those changes.

Comment: FWIW we've noticed the same behavior w/ Artifactory at my company. I may ask our Artifactory folks if it's something we can disable